# MySQL, Gracefully Abort if subquery is Null?

Tags: mysql

I wrote a query that is throwing an error when it can't find a record:

Error

> Column 'product_id' cannot be null

MySQL

```
INSERT INTO orders (date, product_id, quantity)
VALUES ('11/29/2012', (
    SELECT product_id FROM products WHERE product_name = 'Oranges'
), 12)
;
```

I'm actually iterating in my PHP and some of the `product_name` records are not going to exist.

Can I say somehow that if the subquery returns nothing, gracefully stop/abort so the PHP can keep iterating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO orders (date, product_id, quantity)
SELECT '11/29/2012', product_id, 12
FROM products
WHERE product_name = 'Oranges'
```

If there is no matching product, the query will succeed but return no rows modified. If you wish you can read the number of rows modified from PHP when you execute the query.

Notice that if there are multiple products with `product_name = 'Oranges'` you'll get multiple rows inserted into your table.

Comment: Will not insert anything if there's no corresponding row in products.

Comment: @Shedal: Err, yeah... is that a problem?

Comment: @Mark I don't know. Maybe not :) Actually, the description is not really clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a record to be inserted anyway, you can try to fallback to e.g. `0` if no such product exists:

```
INSERT INTO orders (date, product_id, quantity)
VALUES ('11/29/2012', COALESCE((
    SELECT product_id FROM products WHERE product_name = 'Oranges'
), 0), 12);
```

Comment: I didn't know about `COALESCE()`, thanks! Sorry my question isn't clear :(